# Extract percentage slope

Tags: qgis, classification, slope

I have a slope created in percentage of declivity and I class this slope in some ranges (see the image), and I need to know how much % in 0 to 15 in that slope, how much % in 15 to 20 range.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Hypsometric curves` geoalgorithm in `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Raster tools`? As your image shows you already have a (red) bounding polygon, you can use it as the Boundary Layer. Please note `[Save to temporary file]` may not work (tested in 2.18.8), so it will be better to assign a folder to save the output (a csv table).

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, it didn't work.. I need to extract the area of Slope (0-15) and (15-20) then i'll calc the % of this area based in total area polygon.

Comment: i would do it in grass with r.stats